# I wonder how to connect gmail in 2022?

Tags: pantheon-mail

Google has disabled their `less safe apps` option and almost all mail clients need to open `oauth2` popup in order to get the key for specific account. So, any help with this?
I just want to hook up my GMail account to `elementary 6.1` and it fails.

Comment: If you enable 2-factor-authentication (2FA), you can generate a per-app password for Mail. I just tried after a fresh install of OS 7 and it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

There's no any option, rather than to use some different software for your email & calendar, rather than default "Mail" and "Calendar" Elementary apps.

Or to wait until https://github.com/elementary/portals/issues/19 is done.

See the full thread here - https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues/789

Answer (score -1):

This problem was frustrating but, luckily, I came across [this solution](https://www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-add-more-online-accounts-to-elementary-os-by-installing-gnome-control-center/). Here is the gist:

1. From a terminal, update apt (to make sure the package list is up to date):

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install the Gnome Control Center and Online Accounts packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
   ```
3. Enter the following command into the terminal to open Gnome Control Center with some additional flags:

   ```
   Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center –overview
   ```
4. From the left-side list, select "Online Accounts"
5. Add any additional accounts you may want